# Is it just me, or is this an obvious way to see in an instant whether or not a post to review is a test?

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I've been reviewing posts for a while now, and I get tests, like everyone else.

But, is it just me, or is there an **obvious way** to see in an instant **whether or not a post is a test?**

The thing is, I usually apply a filter to review posts more consistently, but the type of test posts seem to be randomly given.

For example, if I have an **Opinion-based filter**, whenever I see a post that have been **flagged as Needs details or clarity**, I know it's a test *(I enjoy clicking on the link to text posts before casting a vote to look at the score!)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For example, if I have an Opinion-based filter, whenever I see a post that have been flagged as Needs details or clarity, I know it's a test (I enjoy clicking on the link to text posts before casting a vote to look at the score!).

The only purpose of audit tests in review queues is to ensure that you're paying attention, and aren't a *robo-reviewer*.

So I see no harm if there are easy ways to determine audits, and won't consider that as a bug.

Comment: We don't need to be paying much attention to glance at the type of flag.

Comment: @AnnZen As mentioned: The point is that you're paying attention at all, regardless how much of it.